# Show only one latest article in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to show the lastest article as a "main" one, so it can be styles differently. Underneath it there should be other latest articles, but without the newest one, so it does not show twice. I currently have this, which duplicates the latest article inside the list, but I am hoping that there should be a better solution, any help much appreciated.

```html
<div class="main-content__container">
            <article>
                <h2>Lastest Article Here</h2>
                <p>Subtitle</p>

                <?php 
                    $latestPost = new WP_Query(array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 1
                    ));

                    while($latestPost->have_posts()) {
                        $latestPost->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="article-older">
                            <h3 class="article-older__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <p class="article-older__description">
                                <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 20) ?>
                            </p>
                            <span><?php the_time('M d') ?></span>
                            <span><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">Read more</a></span>
                        </div>

                    <?php } wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </article>
            
            <div class="article-list">
                <h2>Latest Articles (Without the main one which is above)</h2>
                <?php 
                    $homepagePosts = new WP_Query(array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'offset' => 1  
                    ));

                    while($homepagePosts->have_posts()) {
                        $homepagePosts->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="article-older">
                            <h3 class="article-older__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <p class="article-older__description">
                                <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 20) ?>
                            </p>
                            <span><?php the_time('M d') ?></span>
                            <span><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">Read more</a></span>
                        </div>

                    <?php } wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>

                <p class="btn"><a href="<?php echo site_url('/articles') ?>">View All Articles</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you don’t need pagination here, then simply add an `offset` of 1 to your second query, so that it skips the first post.

Comment: @CBroe ahh, so simple. Thank you! P.S. If you write an answer I wil accept it, put a temp placeholder for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an offset to the second query as recommended by @CBroe

```html
$homepagePosts = new WP_Query(array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'offset' => 1 ));
```